# Rails: Display previously typed input into contact form after it gets unsuccessfully submitted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a contact form in my rails app. If the form did not get successfully submitted, I want the form to display the previously typed input by the user. I would guess that I should use session to contain all the old inputs first, not sure if I'm right though.

The next question is then, how I do get the old inputs to display on the contact form after the page gets refreshed?

This is my code in my controller file:

```
def createMessage
   @message = Message.new(message_params)

  if @message.valid?
    MessageMailer.new_message(@message).deliver
    flash[:success] = "Thank you."
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    session[:message_error] = @message
    flash[:danger] = "An error occurred while delivering this message."
    redirect_to root_path
    @message = session[:message_error]
  end
end
```

And here's my form layout:

```
<%= form_for @message, url: root_path do |message_form| %>
  <div class="form-inline">
     <%= message_form.text_field :first_name, :class => 'form-control', placeholder: "First Name*" %>
     <%= message_form.text_field :last_name, :class => 'form-control', placeholder: "Last Name*" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-inline">
     <%= message_form.text_field :business_title, :class => 'form-control', placeholder: "Business Title" %>
     <%= message_form.text_field :business_name, :class => 'form-control', placeholder: "Business Name" %>
  </div>    

  <div class="form-inline">
     <%= message_form.text_field :phone, :class => 'form-control', placeholder: "Phone*" %>
     <%= message_form.email_field :email, :class => 'form-control', placeholder: "Email*"%>
  </div>     

  <div class="form-group">
     <%= message_form.text_field :street_address, :class => 'form-control', placeholder: "Street Address*" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-addon">Singapore</div>
        <%= message_form.text_field :postal_code, :class => 'form-control', placeholder: "Postal Code*" %>
    </div>
  </div>                            

  <div class="form-group">       
     <%= message_form.text_area :content, :class => 'form-control', placeholder: "Additional information"%>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
     <%= message_form.submit "submit", :class => 'btn btn-default' %>
  </div>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The form_for helper does exactly what you want if it's used properly

In your `new` method you would create a brand new empty message...

```
def new
  @message = Message.new
end
```

So when the 'new' view displays, all the fields are ready for fresh input

In your create method

```
def create

   @message = Message.new(message_params)

  if @message.valid?
    MessageMailer.new_message(@message).deliver
    flash[:success] = "Thank you."
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    flash.now[:danger] = "An error occurred while delivering this message."
    render :new
  end
end
```

Notice that we're doing `render :new` with the @message object which contains the inputted values, so those are automatically displayed.

EDIT - note that flash messages normally display only on `redirect_to` ... to have a flash message display on `render` you need to use `flash.now...`

Answer (score 0):

First, when you can't submit, @message variable is nil so assign variable is useless.

Second, when you redirect_to, you can't assign @message variable.

I'm not sure but i think that you can't use @message variable, instead, you can save message_params to session, and then you can handle it in view.